# User is not fully logged out from Github OAuth app

Tags: oauth-2.0, github-api

I am trying to implement the logout feature for my Github OAuth app. On logout event, the server will invalidate cookies and sessions that hold user's login credentials. The problem is when the user login back to the app, the user is immediately logged in with previous credentials without being asked for username and password. I would like to ask how do I make the user fully log out so that they can log in with other accounts?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?